# YouTube Data API v3 - 403 : Access Not Configured

Tags: java, android, youtube, youtube-api, android-youtube-api

For some reason I cannot get youtube v3 API service configured for an android app. I repeatedly get the error 403 : Access Not Configured.

Example code:

```
try 
    {
        youtube = new YouTube.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, new HttpRequestInitializer() {
            public void initialize(HttpRequest request) throws IOException {}
        }).setApplicationName("appname").build();

        String queryTerm = "MC";

        YouTube.Search.List search = youtube.search().list("id,snippet");

        search.setKey(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY);
        search.setQ(queryTerm);


        search.setType("video");


        search.setFields("items(id/kind,id/videoId,snippet/title,snippet/thumbnails/default/url)");
        search.setMaxResults(NUMBER_OF_VIDEOS_RETURNED);
        SearchListResponse searchResponse = search.execute();

        List<SearchResult> res = searchResponse.getItems();


        return res;
```

I have set the following:

1. Registered a google cloud project in the cloud console.
2. Under API's & Auth I have turned "YouTube Data API v3" ON. It is the only service ON.
3. I have registered my Android application "appname" which matches the argument passed to "setApplicationName" above.
4. I used the Eclipse -> Window -> Preferences -> Android -> Build menu to give me the SHA1 of the debug.keystore. I verified that the package name from my AndroidManifest.xml package="test.project".
5. I have taken the google cloud "Android Key -> Api Key" and set this to the request: search.setKey(DeveloperKey.DEVELOPER_KEY);
6. I have double checked that eclipse is signing the package with the debug.keystore.

I am not using oAuth.

Anyone know what I'm missing?

Cheers,
Jon

Comment: Im going to try calling the rest api directly not through the google classes.

Comment: If I manually post a request to: https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&forMine=true&order=viewCount&type=video&key=MYSECRETKEY it returns: {
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "usageLimits",
    "reason": "accessNotConfigured",
    "message": "Access Not Configured"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Access Not Configured"
 }
} so points for consistency google.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK I am guessing the reason that google was blocking my requests was that they expected any android requests to come via oAuth?

I was able to get this working by registering a web app and using the browser key.